# uiautormator always IllegalStateException:accessibilityservice already registered

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, accessibility

i use uiautomator in junitTest, in "@BeforeClass" i init a UiDevice:
""mUIDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
first i finsh a test,then i start a test again,
i got a error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub$Proxy@7478d40already registered!

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DailyInstrumentedTest  {
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeTest(){


    try {
        mUIDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());  //获得device对象
    }
}
@Test
public void test(){}
}
```